# How to migrate all the AWS lambda function from one region to another region including code using boto3 Python

Tags: function, lambda, move

I am new to python boto3. As per my requirement I need to move lambda function from one region to another region.
Any one could you please help to provide the code snippet on the requirement. I have searched earlier posts in the stackoverflow but it I did not get the correct one

Thanks in advance.

I have tried using lambda_client.get_function and create function but its not worked.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is quite a bit more complicated than just copying the function from one region to another, but it is possible.  Here's some example code that can help get you started.

```
import boto3

profile = "my-aws-profile"
function_name = "hello_world"

# Setup the source region client
kwargs_east = {
    "profile_name": profile,
    "region_name": "us-east-1"
}
session_east = boto3.Session(**kwargs_east)
client_east = session_east.client("lambda")

# Setup the destination region client
kwargs_west = {
    "profile_name": profile,
    "region_name": "us-west-2"
}
session_west = boto3.Session(**kwargs_west)
client_west = session_west.client("lambda")

# Get the details of the source lambda function
response = client_east.get_function(
    FunctionName=function_name
)

# Save the source configuration
lambda_config = response["Configuration"]

# Define Code Location - You'll need to copy the lambda code to a bucket in the destination region
s3_bucket = "my-example-us-west-2"
s3_key = "lambda.py.zip"

# Use the source config and code location to deploy the new function
response = client_west.create_function(
    FunctionName=lambda_config["FunctionName"],
    Runtime=lambda_config["Runtime"],
    Role=lambda_config["Role"],
    Handler=lambda_config["Handler"],
    Code={
        'S3Bucket': s3_bucket,
        'S3Key': s3_key
    },
    Description=lambda_config["Description"],
    Timeout=int(lambda_config["Timeout"]),  # Note you have to cast the string to an int
    MemorySize=int(lambda_config["MemorySize"])  # Note you have to cast the string to an int
)
```

Comment: I have completed this code. Thanks for your help

Comment: Great news.  Go ahead and mark as the answer.